# create OLAP cube in R programming language

Tags: r, olap, data-manipulation, rpivottable

Hi I have following data

```
  Function    SB `Country Region` `+1 Function` `+1 SB` `+1 Country Region`
     <chr> <chr>            <chr>         <chr>   <chr>               <chr>
1      ENG  SB10             AMER           ENG    SB10                AMER
2       IT  SB07             EMEA            IT    SB07                EMEA
3      QLT  SB05             EMEA           QLT    SB05                EMEA
4      MFG  SB07             EMEA           MFG    SB07                EMEA
5      MFG  SB04             EMEA           MFG    SB05                EMEA
6      SCM  SB08             EMEA           SCM    SB08                EMEA
```

i want to create 3 dimensional OLAP cube in which column Function SB Country Region  should be in row and `+1 Function`,`+1 SB`, `+1 Country Region` should be in column .

output should be of following format

```
                   `+1 Function` `+1 SB` `+1 Country Region`  
Function
SB 
Country Region
```

thank you

Adding exact RpivotTable output.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the desired output directly, not just its format?

Comment: Adding exact RpivotTable output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1y1I.png

Comment: Can you confirm the code you used is `rpivotTable::rpivotTable(df, rows = c("Function", "SB", "Country Region"), cols = c("+1 Function", "+1 SB", "+1 Country Region"))` and if so, edit your question to include it?

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `ftable()` for instance:

```
df <- read.table(text =
"  Function    SB 'Country Region' '+1 Function' '+1 SB' '+1 Country Region'
       ENG  SB10             AMER           ENG    SB10                AMER
        IT  SB07             EMEA            IT    SB07                EMEA
       QLT  SB05             EMEA           QLT    SB05                EMEA
       MFG  SB07             EMEA           MFG    SB07                EMEA
       MFG  SB04             EMEA           MFG    SB05                EMEA
       SCM  SB08             EMEA           SCM    SB08                EMEA",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

foo <- ftable(df, row.vars = c(3, 1, 2), col.vars = c(6, 4, 5))

as.matrix(foo)[apply(foo, 1, function(x) any(x != 0)), apply(foo, 2, function(x) any(x != 0))]
# Or simply:
as.matrix(foo)[apply(foo, 1, any), apply(foo, 2, any)]

#                           +1 Country Region_+1 Function_+1 SB
# Country Region_Function_SB AMER_ENG_SB10 EMEA_IT_SB07 EMEA_MFG_SB05 EMEA_MFG_SB07 EMEA_QLT_SB05 EMEA_SCM_SB08
#              AMER_ENG_SB10             1            0             0             0             0             0
#              EMEA_IT_SB07              0            1             0             0             0             0
#              EMEA_MFG_SB04             0            0             1             0             0             0
#              EMEA_MFG_SB07             0            0             0             1             0             0
#              EMEA_QLT_SB05             0            0             0             0             1             0
#              EMEA_SCM_SB08             0            0             0             0             0             1
```

Comparison with `rpivotTable::rpivotTable(df, rows = c("Country Region", "Function", "SB"), cols = c("+1 Country Region", "+1 Function", "+1 SB"))`:

[image]

Comment: thanks Aurèle this  worked for sample but when i am applying it on complete data i am missing out some combination. what I want all the combination of row and column and where their is no match found in data it should give me Zero (0)......can you help me in that

Comment: Is just `foo` what you want then?

Comment: It does indeed.

Comment: Nothing. `foo` should be in your workspace already if you've run it. Just type `foo` again then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the command line to print it

Comment: thanks for your valuable inputs i just seen foo output it gives me frequency and now i want matrix can you help me in it

Comment: `as.matrix(foo)`?

Comment: i have tried as.matrix on my data it should give me same no of row and column matrix but its not giving that......any other work around?