# Create OLAP cube in R- programming

Tags: r, olap

Can we create OLAP cube using R .can any one give me an example to understand and apply to my data .Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a detailed example: http://horicky.blogspot.fr/2013/07/olap-operation-in-r.html

Comment: Also see my answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45794052/6197649

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create OLAP cube in R programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732518/create-olap-cube-in-r-programming-language)